# Property 'paginator' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

This is my component.ts file

import {AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';`

`
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({

selector: 'app-table-component',

templateUrl: './table-component.component.html',

styleUrls: ['./table-component.component.css']
})

export class TableComponentComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngAfterViewInit() {

this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

}

}

export interface PeriodicElement {

name: string;

position: number;

weight: number;

symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [

{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},

{position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},

{position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},

{position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},

{position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},

{position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},

{position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},

{position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},

{position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},

{position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},

{position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},

{position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},

{position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},

{position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},

{position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},

{position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},

{position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},

{position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},

{position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},

{position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},

];

Comment: Please edit the post and format the code as it is very difficult to read.

Comment: I guess `paginator` class field is missing here. Please declare it first.